# HIbernate onetoMany mapping on non unique column

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-boot

I have three tables player, Match and media as below

```
Player
    player_id-->PK
    Media_id

Match
    match_id-->PK
    Media_id

Media
   Media_internal_id --> PK
   Media_id 
   Other_details
```

Media id is non unique column can have duplicate value and it is the joining column.
now i want to load all media Object associated with player

Tried Below

```
Player{
    @OneToMany
    @Formula("SELECT * FROM MEDIA WHERE MEDIA_ID = MEDIA_ID")
        private List<Media> media= new ArrayList<Media>();
}
```

**RepositoryCode**

```
@Repository
public interface PlayerRepository extends JpaRepository<Player, Integer>{

    @Query(value="  SELECT P.* FROM PLAYER P  ", nativeQuery=true)   
    public List<Player> findAllPlayer();

}
```

**Error:**

```
o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Table 'tennis.PLAYER_media' doesn't exist
```

How can it be mapped?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the primary key for a ralationship.

Below is the unidirectional example.

```
Player{
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "player_id")
    private List<Media> media= new ArrayList<Media>();
}
```

Player:
  player_id --> PK
  Other_details

Media:
   Media_id --> PK
   player_id --> JoinColumn
   Other_details

Comment: if i map on primary key (Media_internal_id), then each player can map only to one media Object. In my case each player can map to multiple media Object. So i added  non unique column media id , which is mapped in player

Comment: @upog I've corrected the answer. A player can have multiple media and a media has only one player. This is what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your time, but i can not go for this design as you see media will be child of multiple entity like player, matches, tournaments etc. if i start adding player_id to Media, then i have to include primary key of all parents